# Java generics: actual class as a generic parameter

Tags: java, generics

What do I write instead of "TheClass" to make this work? Or is there an alternative way to do it (possibly without making WithName and WithAge generic)?

```
class Item {
 NeigborList<TheClass> neighbors;
}

class WithName extends Item { // here I want neighbors to be a NeighborList<WithName>
 String name;
 void someMethod() {
  System.out.println(neighbors.nearestTo(this).name);
 }
}

class WithAge extends Item { // here I want neighbors to be a NeighborList<WithAge>
 int age;
 void someOtherMethod() {
  System.out.println(neighbors.nearestTo(this).age);
 }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest that you try to choose names which describe the concepts as accurately as possible. "Item" will almost certainly be too general. If you can work out what Item is then it will help you to model the system

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you wanted to say this

```
class Item <T> {
    NeigborList<T> neighbors;
}

class WithName extends Item<WithName> {
    ...
}
```